# Does this theorem have a name?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I don't know the name of the following theorem, or even if it has a name.

If $P(A) = P(B)$, and $P(A | C) = P(B | C)$, then $P(C | A) = P(C | B)$

Proof. Suppose (i) $P(A) = P(B)$ and (ii) $P(A | C) = P(B | C)$. Then:
\begin{align}
\frac{P(A\wedge C)}{P(C)} &= \frac{P(B\wedge C)}{P(C)}\quad \textrm{(From (ii))}\\
P(A\wedge C) &= P(B\wedge C)\\
\frac{P(A\wedge C)}{P(A)}  &= \frac{P(B\wedge C)}{P(A)}\\
\frac{P(A\wedge C)}{P(A)} &= \frac{P(B\wedge C)}{P(B)}\quad \textrm{(From (i))}\\
P(C|A) &= P(C|B)
\end{align}
Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: In his classical book on probability theory, Feller recommends do not give name to "theorems" like that. They are just obvious consequences of the definition of conditional probability, obtained by means of some simple algebra.

Comment: Both your theorem and your proof implicitly assume some values are non-zero.  You should state these assumptions, as otherwise there are counter-examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially an implication of Bayes' theorem.  Assuming the various probabilities are nonzero, which you do implicitly,

$$\frac{\Pr(C|B)}{\Pr(C|A)} = \frac{ \frac{\Pr(B|C) \Pr(C)}{\Pr(B)}}{\frac{\Pr(A|C) \Pr(C)}{\Pr(A)}}=1.
$$